# How to Vertically Center a Container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Flutter project and have encountered an issue with vertically centering a container within a page. My goal is to achieve a layout similar to the second screenshot provided, where the container is centered vertically on the screen, unlike my current layout where it starts at the top.

**Current Design:**

[image]

**Desired Design:**

[image]

Despite wrapping the container with a `Center` widget, the container remains aligned at the top. Below is the relevant part of my code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: LongBreak ? const Color(0xffD94530) : const Color(0xff6351c5),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
         //...code
        },
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: controller,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
           //...code
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Responsive(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        // This is the container I'm trying to center vertically
                        Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          height: 210,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            color: const Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                          ),
                         //...code
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

For some reason, I'm unable to center the timer container vertically. I've tried using the `Center` widget, but had no luck. Any guidance on how to achieve this layout would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: I have tried to interpret and give solution. If you precisely would want to know the answer, please produce precise overview code. I can help you out then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its difficult to figure out the complete code because of lots of code and incorrect indentation. But as far as I can see, you are facing this problem because of using `Spacer`,

`Spacer` is pushing your `floating button` and the `timer Container` to its ends.

Try removing the `Spacer` and wrap the `timer Container` with `Center` and wrap it with `Flexible` this should solve your problem.

Your present code is roughly:

```
Column
|_ Timer Container
|_ Spacer
|_ Floating Button
```

Change it to:

```
Column
|_ Flexible
  |_ Center
    |_ Timer Container
|_ Floating Button
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use `Stack` widget, use positional widget like `Aling`, `Positioned` on Stack. Based on your UI, using stack widget structure will be

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    background(context),
    Align(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: buildCounter(context),
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: startPauseButtonBuild(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Here is the full snippet, I've removed some part for minimal and padding widget to handle some space

```dart
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: const StartPomodoro()));

class StartPomodoro extends StatefulWidget {
  const StartPomodoro({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<StartPomodoro> createState() => _StartPomodoroState();
}

class _StartPomodoroState extends State<StartPomodoro>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final now = DateTime.now();

  List<bool> isSelected = [true, false];
  late Timer timer;
  late AnimationController controller;

  String get countText {
    Duration count = controller.duration! * controller.value;
    return controller.isDismissed
        ? '${controller.duration!.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(controller.duration!.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(controller.duration!.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'
        : '${count.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  double progress = 1.0;
  bool LongBreak = true;

  void notify() {
    if (countText == '00:00:00') {}
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
    );
    controller.addListener(() {
      notify();
      if (controller.isAnimating) {
        setState(() {
          progress = controller.value;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          progress = 1.0;
          LongBreak = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor:
            LongBreak ? const Color(0xffD94530) : const Color(0xff6351c5),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: controller,
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    background(context),
                    Align(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: buildCounter(context),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: startPauseButtonBuild(),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget startPauseButtonBuild() {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (_, constraints) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: controller,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                    backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(
                      controller.isAnimating ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                      color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      controller.isAnimating ? "Pause" : "Start",
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xff3B3B3B)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column buildCounter(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 210,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: const Color(0xffFAFAFA)),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "Hyper-focused on... (+add task)",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    Center(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  countText,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    letterSpacing: 4,
                                    fontSize: 65.0,
                                    color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: const [
                                Text(
                                  '    Hours      Minutes     Seconds    ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    letterSpacing: 2,
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Align background(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        color: const Color(0xffD94530),
        height: controller.value * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.722,
      ),
    );
  }

  AnimationController _buildClockAnimation(TickerProvider tickerProvider) {
    return AnimationController(
      vsync: tickerProvider,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 750),
    );
  }

  void _animateLeftDigit(
    int prev,
    int current,
    AnimationController controller,
  ) {
    final prevFirstDigit = (prev / 10).floor();
    final currentFirstDigit = (current / 10).floor();
    if (prevFirstDigit != currentFirstDigit) {
      controller.forward();
    }
  }
}
```